# How to display what the user is typing in a JTextField in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

The user will be typing the player's name in a JTextField placed inside a JPanel, so I want to display what he's typing in another area of the panel beside a Label that says 'Player:'. So, for example, if the user typed "Steve", then I want the string Steve to appear beside the JLabel Player character by character; the same way the user is typing it. How can I do that?!

Comment: That can be done by registering a DocumentListener on the JTextField's document. But why  do you want do that? Why not have the input JTextField placed next to the JLabel in the first place?

Comment: @thelili018 I don't know how else to reach you now that you've deleted your other question.  (I went to bed after my last comment there).  But the answer to that one was that the JPEG format doesn't store the colours of individual pixels, and it doesn't support sharp edges between zones of colour.  It's more about storing degrees of shading, so you always get extra colours along the colour boundaries.  If you had stored your greyscale image as a different format (maybe GIF), then you'd have got each pixel saved with the intended colour.

Comment: And it would be good if you could undelete that question so I can post the above as an answer.  It may be useful to other users of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote a working example to make it clear to you. Hope it helps!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel label;

    void createAndShowGUI() {

        textField = new JTextField("TextField");
        this.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        label = new JLabel("Label");
        this.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener(label));

        this.setSize(512, 128);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test().createAndShowGUI());
    }

}

class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    private JLabel targetComponent;

    public MyDocumentListener(JLabel component) {
        this.targetComponent = component;
    }

    private void update(DocumentEvent e) {
        try {
            targetComponent.setText(e.getDocument().getText(0, e.getDocument().getLength()));
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyDocumentListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update(e);
    } 
}
```

If you still have got questions, feel free asking in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field. Then you will get notification whenever the text in the text field is changed.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and working examples.